# как посчитать процент несовпадений

Tags: python

[image: поэлементно сравнить и процент несовпадений получить]

поэлементно сравнить и процент несовпадений получить, хотя бы примерно от чего отталкиваться

Comment: `sum(x[0] != x[1] for x in массив) * 100.0 / len(массив)`

Comment: Ещё (возможно рабочий) вариант с numpy: `np.mean(a == b) * 100`, или `(a == b).mean() * 100`

Comment: Если речь о Numpy массивах, то вариант от @diraria `(a != b).mean() * 100` - как раз то, что вам нужно...

Comment: спасибо, очень благодарна)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы напечатать процент несовпадений для двух numpy массивов (вариант из комментариев):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 0])
b = np.array([0, 1, 1])
print('{:.1%}'.format((a != b).mean()))  # -> 33.3%
```

Comment: спасииибо Вам огромное!

Comment: а как прописать, чтоб из файла CSV  читал и сравнивал, там 112 значений и думаю мое препод не примет, если я все значения вручную пропишу

Comment: @user280357: в комментариях не стоит новые вопросы задавать. Если не нашли существующий вопрос: "как прочитать csv файл как numpy массив", то можно отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос задать.